# Nautilus File Browser Shows Details For Choosen Item

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

I want to see more details especially last modified date for chosen item on nautilus as shown in below screenshot. Nautilus only gives size information as default. Is there any way to improve default one?

This kind of details can be received for list items view type.

Windows has information hover when your mouse is on an item. I tried to find something similar on Ubuntu but it seems that there are some requests still opened for years.

[image: nautilus]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can choose 3 information items to show below files in the preferences

[image]

You'll need to zoom in to see all the data

f.ex.

[image]

If you want to request a new feature in nautilus/files app I think you should use https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes i checked that options but this needs to zoomed view and shows for all files in that directory. My concerning is about for specific chosen files with mouse.